# controlling floating point optimizations OS X C++ compiler

Tags: c++, macos, floating-point, floating-accuracy

Is the system C++ compiler with Mac OS X (El Capitan) using strict IEEE floating point behavior by default?  I am trying to debug some differences between Mac OS X and Linux, and I think it might be related to compiler optimizations.

The compiler man page didn't seem to have any insight into controlling floating point behavior?

Comment: What aspects of "floating point behaviour" are you looking to control? What is the problem you are observing? What does your code look like? Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that the hardware and compiler endeavours to be compatible with IEEE 754. There may be some bugs of course. Generally I would **not** expect different platforms to produce identical results, in particular due to small differences in the output of the standard library maths functions.

I presume that by the 'system C++ compiler' you mean XCode and clang. clang (and g++) do have some optimisations that can generate code that will cause differences, e.g. see [-ffast-math](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FloatingPointMath) - link for GCC but clang is probably the same.

Comment: The gcc compilers tend to be compliant, by default.  Lossy math optimizations have to be explicitly turned on.  Both the Microsoft Visual Studio and Intel compilers make some very aggressive optimizations that can result in numerical precision loss.  Their flags are documented.  I couldn't find anything for the Mac OS X compilers.

Comment: I can't access pastebin from my work computer. This page https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html lists -ffast-math for clang.

Comment: Thanks.  I am using the system c++ compiler for El Capitan, which is clang.  I have not seen any documentation from Apple on what they do for floating point behavior.